Does sys_brk zero-initialize memory when extended on Linux?
sys_brk or just brk is used to extend the available memory of a program. When I extend memory it does appear to be zero-initialized. However, I was wondering if this behavior is guaranteed by the operating system, or just a coincidence.

Anytime Linux gives a process new memory, it must initialize the memory to prevent one process from seeing sensitive data left over from another process or the operating system. So whenever new pages are mapped into your process, they are cleared. However, brk (which is archaic now) can be used with positive or negative amounts. If you deallocate memory (within the accounting of your process, so it is not returned to the operating system) and reallocate it, the memory is not necessarily cleared at that point.

(Theoretically, an operating system could track memory so that it knows your process freed some particular page earlier and is now asking for new memory, possibly at a different virtual address. In that case, the operating system might give you back the previous memory without clearing it. I am not aware of any general-purpose multiuser system that has implemented this.)

FWIW glibc's calloc assumes that sbrk zeros the memory. See here but of course there are other assumptions built in, such as that you only increment by full memory pages. It's Linux policy not to break userspace programs with kernel changes so this behvaior will hold for the foreseeable future. However, sbrk has been removed from the POSIX standard for over 20 years. None of this is portable.

For the record, it is sbrk that can be used with positive or negative arguments.  brk takes an absolute address, and is therefore even more obsolete, and just about impossible to use safely.  (Theoretically your program could use sbrk in conjunction with a carefully-written malloc.  Not so with brk, which will undermine any other library code that's doing anything with the heap.)

(It's true, I suppose, that you can use brk to get the same effect as a negative argument to sbrk, but brk is so impossible to use safely that I don't consider it that interesting to talk about at all.)
